# Javascript action when user stops typing

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="value"/>

<script>
var timer = null;
$('#qty').keydown(function(){
   clearTimeout(timer); 
param = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    alert('a param : ' + param);        
}, 1000)
});
</script>
```

This should create and alert when the user stops typing. There is a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/msmJp/1/

However I cannot seem to get it working on my end.

Comment: Can you show that you've included jQuery? Also your code isn't inside dom ready `$(function(){});` Can you show that the dom is ready in your code?

Comment: Should work fine if you've included JQuery, there's nothing wrong with your code. Please post console errors that you are seeing (Developer/Javascript Console)

Comment: I failed to include jQuery, thanks for pointing that out. I must of been up too late. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While OP found his answer in simply having forgotten to include jQuery, I figure I'll take this chance to throw you all a snippet that can make things like this easier to deal with. (*not that it's really hard*)

The following makes things like `typing stopped -> do action` issues as simple as a single method call.

```
/** debounce(callback, arguments, delay, object)
 *  Method to help reduce multifire issues 
 **/
;(function() {
function debounce(cb, args, delay, obj) {
    void 0 == obj && (obj = window);
    obj['__debounce_timer__'] && clearTimeout(obj['__debounce_timer__']);
    args = 'object' == typeof args ? Array.prototype.slice.call(args) : void 0 != args ? [args] : arguments;
    (0 > delay || "number" != typeof delay) && (delay = 250);   //  250 milliseconds as a default delay time
    return obj['__debounce_timer__'] = setTimeout(function() { delete obj['__debounce_timer__']; cb.apply(obj, args); }, delay);
}
window.hasOwnProperty("debounce") || (window.debounce = debounce);
})();
```

### Example Using OP's Q:

```
$('#qty').keydown(function(e){
    debounce(
        function() {
            param = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            alert('a param : ' + param);    
        },
        arguments,  //  in this case [e]
        1000,   //  time in milliseconds || default 250 milliseconds
        this    //  or simply void 0 || undefined || {}
    );
});
```

---

Just for fun, here's an extended version. ***¡CAUTION!*** The following version adds `debounce` to the `Function` object.

```
/** debounce(callback, arguments, delay, object)    ||  Function.debounce(arguments, delay, object)
 *  Method to help reduce multifire issues 
 **/
;(function() {
    function debounce(cb, args, delay, obj) {
        void 0 == obj && (obj = window);
        obj['__debounce_timer__'] && clearTimeout(obj['__debounce_timer__']);
        args = 'object' == typeof args ? Array.prototype.slice.call(args) : void 0 != args ? [args] : arguments;
        (0 > delay || "number" != typeof delay) && (delay = 250);   //  250 milliseconds as a default delay time
        return obj['__debounce_timer__'] = setTimeout(function() { delete obj['__debounce_timer__']; cb.apply(obj, args); }, delay);
    }
    window.hasOwnProperty("debounce") || (window.debounce = debounce);
    /** CAUTION APPENDS TO FUNCTION OBJECT **/
    function funcDebounce(args, delay, obj) { return debounce(this, args, delay, obj); }
    if (window.debounce === debounce) {
        Object['defineProperty'] && !Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty('funcDebounce')
            ? Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'debounce', { value: funcDebounce })
                : Function.prototype.debounce = funcDebounce;
    }
})();
```

### Example Using OP's Q:

```
function opCallBack() {
    param = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    alert('a param : ' + param);
}

$('#qty').keydown(function(e){
    opCallBack.debounce(arguments, 1000, this);
});
```

#### Running Example

```js
function callBack() { $('#jon').removeClass('typeing').text('FINISHED TYPEING'); }
$('#bob').on('keyup', function(e) {
 $('#jon').addClass('typeing').text('typeing ...');
 debounce(callBack);
});
```

```css
html, body, table { height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
textarea { height: 8em; width: 16em; }
.typeing { background-color: #FCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/debounce/1be19005/debounce.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <textarea id="bob" type="text" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
   <br />
   <div id="jon"></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```